# Line No 1 Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined

Tags: sku

Hi can any one help me to fix this error I am not able to upload any product I am gating this error (Line No 1 Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.)  I am uploading the Sku like this sku
NAY101-Maroon and image like this nay101-maroon-_1__1.jpg I am fade up while uploading this file can any one help me into that. my email is info@shoppingara.com

Answer (score 0):

Please open your **CSV** file in text editor and make sure it looks like below.

```
"sku","image"
"NAY101-Maroon","/nay101-maroon-_1__1.jpg"
```

And that image must be in **media/import** folder.

Comment: Hi I tried to upload Csv    Like this "NAY101-Maroon","/nay101-maroon-_1__1.jpg" still I am gating the same error I dnt know what is the problem I tried many way

Comment: Which editor or software you are using ?

Comment: 1.9 of magento I really appreciate that you are helping me